# Oracle Timezone Conversion & Query Optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a calculated subscriber frequency table (~40M) for more than 5 countries:

```
DB: Oracle 11g

Minimal Schema: ID - Integer, Freq - Varchar
```

So basically, I am trying to extract the subscribers dynamically based on every day.

```
Frequency Chart (May differ based for each countries):

7X - Everyday
5X - All weekdays
3X - Monday, Wednesday, Friday
2X - Tuesday, Thursday
1X - Wednesday
```

I have written the following query which will give different list every day (*Modified*^ for better understanding):

```
SELECT ID
FROM (
    WITH CONST AS (
            SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 5 / 8), 'D') TODAY_
            FROM DUAL
            )
    SELECT C.ID
        ,FREQ
        ,CASE 
            WHEN FREQ = '7X'
                THEN TODAY_
            WHEN FREQ = '5X'
                AND TODAY_ NOT IN (
                    1
                    ,7
                    )
                THEN TODAY_
            WHEN FREQ = '3X'
                AND TODAY_ IN (
                    2
                    ,4
                    ,6
                    )
                THEN TODAY_
            WHEN FREQ = '2X'
                AND TODAY_ IN (
                    3
                    ,5
                    )
                THEN TODAY_
            WHEN FREQ = '1X'
                AND TODAY_ = 4
                THEN TODAY_
            END AS TARGET_
    FROM CONST
        ,CONTACT C
    INNER JOIN ENGAGEMENT ENG ON C.ID = ENG.ID
        AND C.COUNTRY_ID = '1'
    )
WHERE TARGET_ IS NOT NULL
```

I have two questions

1) In the `CONST` sub query I am trying to convert PST to ICT. Is there any other better way to convert timezones in oracle

2) Since I have different queries based on each country. Each query takes around and sometimes more than 5-10 minutes to fetch the results. I am not sure how optimized the query is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not rely on `TO_CHAR(..., 'D')`, because the result depends on current settings of `NLS_TERRITORY` which can be different on each session. Also `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` can be different, so it is better to specify it explicitly.

`ICT` is not a valid time zone name, I assume you mean 'Asia/Bangkok'. `PST` is also ambiguous.

This one should work:

```
WITH t AS
    (SELECT
        TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Bangkok', 'fmDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american' ) AS TODAY
    FROM dual) 
SELECT ID
FROM CONTACT C
    INNER JOIN ENGAGEMENT ENG ON C.ID = ENG.ID
    CROSS JOIN t
WHERE C.COUNTRY_ID = 1
    AND (
        (FREQ = '7X') 
        OR (FREQ = '5X' AND TODAY NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday') )
        OR (FREQ = '3X' AND TODAY IN ('Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday') )
        OR (FREQ = '2X' AND TODAY IN ('Tuesday', 'Thursday') )
        OR (FREQ = '1X' AND TODAY IN ('Wednesday') )
    );
```